# Adding a Custom Field to the Sign-in Page in Azure B2C

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm wondering if there's a way to include a custom field on the Sign-in page in Azure B2C using custom policy. My goal is to add a checkbox for users to consent to cookies. Currently, I've tried a simple solution with custom HTML and JavaScript, but it can be bypassed by password manager tools like Bitwarden. I think the B2C server needs to be involved to validate the checkbox before allowing the login submission to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add any more B2C fields to the sign-in page, or any page using the `unifiedssp` [data URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#datauri).

That leaves five options I can think of:

1. Have a self-asserted page before the sign-in page with the checkbox. This would work and you could prevent people getting to the login screen. Although, this does add another step for the user and a worse user experience IMO.
2. Disable password managers on the sign-in screen. Again, a worse user experience.
3. Override the sign-in button's submit function and check the checkbox status.
4. Not include the checkbox requirement. In theory, the user will have been prompted from the website if they accept cookies, or not. If they do not, they wouldn't be able to click the sign-in button to get to the login page.
5. As the B2C cookies are functional cookies (essential for the platform to work), you can get away with an information bar at the bottom stating "by using this service you consent to the use of essential cookies. ". You can see an example of that on the [Entra News](https://entra.news/) website.

---

*Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.*